VS code terminal command line abnormal colour behaviour after Copilot install
Few days ago. I have started to notice that my VS Code terminal is behaving weird. Despite having a black background, the lines having text are marked as white. Not sure, why is this happening. I have installed GitHub Copilot and it auto complete my git commands. Is it due to the auto-complete? Or is it something else, that I might have messed up?. Although, it's not only for Git commands, but any command that I run in the terminal (for ex: Python execution).
As far as I remember, I haven't played with the VS Code settings for sometime. Does anyone here have faced the same?

Ctrl Shift P, Open Settings (Json) and delete all customer settings if have. Otherwise you may try to reinstall the latest VSCode

None of them worked.  After re-installation, the previous settings got loaded automatically. I think even after system restart, VS code stored it's configuration file somewhere, which is why post fresh installation the settings were the same.
